# Using boost program options under Visual Studio MSVC 14.0 Assertion failed

Tags: c++, boost, boost-program-options

I have compiled Boost 1.66 under MSVC 14.0. I'm trying to port an existing project which works fine under Boost on Linux to Visual Studio.

That's the piece of code that fails:

```
options.add_options()
            ("help", "Produce help message")
            ("config-file,c", po::value<string>(&config_file_path)->default_value("config.xml"), "Configuration file path")
            ("port,p", po::value<int>(&html_port)->default_value(7999), "HTTP Server port")
            ("html_root,hr", po::value<string>(&html_root)->default_value("."), "Directory root for HTML page");
```

With the following assertion:

```
Assertion failed: n == name.size()-2, file libs\program_options\src\options_description.cpp, line 177
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think option short name (after comma) should be a single char, that is `,hr"` should be `,r"`

Comment: Thank you. Indeed that was the problem. I didn't thought of that because it works on ubuntu and also works in windows under mingw64.

Comment: Also, can you please tell me how 
`options.add_options()
            ("help", "Produce help message")`
is valid C++ syntax? I don't get it.

Comment: @FakherMokadem `options.add_options()` returns a reference to object with overloaded `operator ()` that takes two arguments and so on.